# PHP regex match only one double quote

Tags: php, regex

Im trying to match a line of code which only has one double quote ("). I have tried:

```
\"{1}
```

on the following strings

```
"this is a string"
"this is a string
```

the regex should only match the second line but it matches both of them.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: It matches both because both have a quote. Your regex is wrong

Comment: but {1} should only match exactly one

Comment: Yeah. One, but nothing else. It sees the one quote, reaches the end of the regex and sez good

Comment: I see, thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the not group.

```
^[^\"]*\"[^\"]*$
```

Comment: It's called a *negated character class*.

Comment: @AlanMoore: I should have given the official name too, especially as _group_ officially means a parenthesized sub-expression. But I find it a bit hard to use _negated character class_ in an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find out if there is only one double-quote character on any given line, try this:

```
/^[^"]*"[^"]*$/m
```

Note the `m` modifier - this allows `^` and `$` to match the start and end of any given line, as opposed to just the start and end of the matched string.

Comment: isn't escaping the double-quotes necessary?

Comment: @gopi1410: Double-quotes have no special meaning in a regex.  You only have to escape them if you write the regex in the form of a double-quoted string: `"/^[^\"]*\"[^\"]*$/m"`.  But you can always use single-quotes instead: `'/^[^"]*"[^"]*$/m'`.